# Group by and select in Enity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core

I have this model:

```
public class Evento: Base
{
    public string Pais { get; set; }
    public string Regiao { get; set; }
    public string Estado { get; set; }
    public string Evento{ get; set; }
    public double Valor { get; set; }
    public long Time { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the query I'm working on:

```
IQueryable<Evento> query = _context.Eventos;

        return query.AsNoTracking()
                     .GroupBy(s => new { s.Regiao, s.Pais })
                     .Select(ss => new Evento
                     {
                         Pais = ss.Key.Pais,
                         Regiao = ss.Key.Regiao,
                         Valor = ss.Sum(soma => soma.Valor),
                         Evento = ??
                     }).ToList();
```

I want a Linq query to generate an output which is equivalent to the data represented as below:

```
    ________________________________________________
   |   Pais    |   Regiao  |  Evento    |  Valor   |
   |- Argentina|- Oeste    |- Evento02  |- 2675.0  |
   |- Brasil   |- Sudeste  |- Evento01  |- 1800.0  |
   |- Brasil   |- Sul      |- Eventor02 |- 2700.0  |
```

I need to extrating field "Evento" to Evento-Object in the result-list. How can i achieve that?

Comment: If your "Evento" field contains "Sensor01" and "Sensor02" values for each of the rows, then you'll need to provide more information how you want to get to "Evento02", "Evento01", and "Eventor02" from "Sensor01" and "Sensor02" for each of the raw data entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the output I wanted using this code:

```
    IEnumerable<Evento> query = _context.Evento;

    var dynamicQuery = query.GroupBy(s => new { s.Regiao, s.Pais })
                 .Select(ss => new
                 {
                     Regiao = ss.Key.Regiao,
                     Pais = ss.Key.Pais,
                     Evento = ss.GroupBy(n => n.Evento)
                                    .Select(s => new { 
                                        Evento = s.Key,
                                        Valor = s.Sum(v => v.Valor)
                                    }).ToList()
                 }).ToList();

    return dynamicQuery;
```

Output:

```
________________________________________________
|   Pais    |   Regiao  |  Evento    |  Valor   |
|- Argentina|- Oeste    |- Evento02  |- 2675.0  |
|- Brasil   |- Sudeste  |- Evento01  |- 1800.0  |
|- Brasil   |- Sul      |- Eventor02 |- 2700.0  |
```

Thank you all for the support.

Comment: What difference does this have with the other solutions provided, which are simpler?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you want to group by `Evento`, but for some reason it isn't included in your `GroupBy`. Adding it, we get the following:

```
IQueryable<Evento> query = _context.Eventos;

return query.AsNoTracking()
             .GroupBy(s => new { s.Regiao, s.Pais, s.Evento })
             .Select(ss => new Evento
             {
                 Pais = ss.Key.Pais,
                 Regiao = ss.Key.Regiao,
                 Valor = ss.Sum(soma => soma.Valor),
                 Evento = ss.Key.Evento
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: @Lucas Then your question needs to explain how to get from Sensor01 / Sensor02 for each of the Country/Region/Event combinations. And ideally provide code in your question to build the sample input list.

Comment: @LucasFernandes, as per your comment, there are two entries for Brasil/Sudeste, which sum 1800. But in your post, you are displaying "Evento01". Where does that come from? Your data doesn't even have the word "evento" but "sensor". Same thing with Brasil/Sul. You display "Eventor02" (extra 'r' I guess) but your data is again just "sensor" (01 and 02).

Answer (score 1):

*GroupBy()* uses the object you create (**Regiao** and **Pais** in your example) as the unique key for each group. Since the key does not contain **Evento**, you can't access **Evento** through the group's *Key* property. Each group contains one or more **Evento** objects. Since there can be more than one, you have to decide which object's **Evento** property you want to return in the *Select()*.

For example, this query chooses the **Evento** property of the first **Evento** object in the group:

```
query.AsNoTracking()
    // Regiao and Pais form the unique key for each group
    .GroupBy(s => new { s.Regiao, s.Pais })
    // For each Evento object in each group...
    .Select(ss =>
        // Construct a new Evento object from the Key,
        // the sum of all Valor properties, and the Evento
        // property of the first Event object in the group.
        new Evento
        {
            Pais = ss.Key.Pais,
            Regiao = ss.Key.Regiao,
            Valor = ss.Sum(soma => soma.Valor),
            Evento = ss.First().Evento
        }
    )
    .ToList();
```

This might not be what you want to do, but I hope it gives you more insight into how to use *GroupBy()*.

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results) can give you more useful detail.